# How to add 'click' event listener or access 'ref' that's mentioned in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2

Here is my data that looks something like this:

```
cars: [
  {
    id: 1,
    desc: 'Description with <a ref="id1" @click="openModel('my-car')">a link</a> lorem ipsum continues.'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    desc: 'Description without link'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    desc: 'Description with <a ref="id3" @click="openAnotherModel('my-dashboard')">a link</a> lorem ipsum continues.'
  }
]
```

In my template I can do:

```
<p v-for="item in cars" v-html="item"></p>
```

and of course this certainly not going works:

```
<p v-for="item in cars">{{ item }}</p>
```

How to access my methods/functions that's defined in my vue instance:

```
methods: {
  openModel(str) {
    console.log('openModel :>> ', str);
  },
  openAnotherModel(str) {
    console.log('openAnotherModel :>> ', str);
  },
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited after comment.

You can access your links from the mounted event hooks, like so.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    cars: [
      {
        id: 1,
        desc: `Description with <a href="my-car">a link</a> lorem ipsum continues.`
      }, {
        id: 2,
        desc: `Description without link`
      }, {
        id: 3,
        desc: `Description with <a href="dash-board">a link</a> lorem ipsum continues.`
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    dispatchLink(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      const target = e.target;
      const str = target.getAttribute('href');
      
      switch(str) {
          case 'my-car':
            this.openModel(str)
            break;
          case 'dash-board':
            this.openAnotherModel(str)
            break;
          // other link type ...
        }
    },
    openModel(str) {
      console.log('openModel :>> ', str);
    },
    openAnotherModel(str) {
      console.log('openAnotherModel :>> ', str);
    }
  },
  mounted(){
      const carsLinks = this.$el.querySelectorAll('p a');
      carsLinks.forEach(link => link.addEventListener('click', this.dispatchLink)       
      )
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p 
    v-for="car in cars" 
    :key="car.id" 
    v-html="car.desc"
    :id="car.id"
  >
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying and I do not have access to data structure, text can also come after end of link tag `Description with <a ref="id3" @click="openAnotherModel('my-dashboard')">a link</a> lorem ipsum continues.` sorry! your solution did not help. thanks again.

Comment: I see ... edited my answer accordingly, hope this helps.

Comment: surely deserves +1 up vote :) almost there but my anchor tag needs to pass parameters. eg: `openModel('my-car')` , `openAnotherModel('my-dashboard')`

Comment: you can check in JS `if(str === 'my-car')` there can be many different string like this `'my-car`

Comment: It's just a mater of conditions (depending on the link href content, there are many ways to achieve this, it's up to you to adapt it according to your needs ... edited my answer (added a dispatch function and a switch statement)

Comment: thanks for your answer, Even I have posted my answer, Just in case if you are curious what I ended up with :)

Comment: like I said "there are many ways to achieve this" and your solution is the best suited for you ... Glad I helped, good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up with for the question that I have asked. Instead of figuring out how to make `@click="myFun('myData')"` work, I used `data-image="myData"`

```
<template lang="pug">
  div(ref="cars")
    .row.no-gutters(v-for="(item, index) in cars" :key="index")
      p(v-html="item.desc")
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      cars: [
        {
          id: 1,
          desc: 'Some text about <a href="#" onClick="return false;" class="jsOpenImgModal" data-image="/images/dash.png">dash</a> lorem ipsum continues.',
        }, {
          id: 2,
          desc: 'Description without link',
        }, {
          id: 3,
          desc: 'And, Some text about <a href="#" onClick="return false;" class="jsOpenImgModal" data-image="/image/front.png">front</a> lorem ipsum continues.',
        },
      ],
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    const imgModals = this.$refs.cars.querySelectorAll('.jsOpenImgModal');

    Object.keys(imgModals).forEach((i) => {
      const imgUrl = imgModals[i].dataset.image;
      imgModals[i].addEventListener('click', () => this.fnImgModals(imgUrl));
    });
  },

  methods: {
    fnImgModals(imgUrl) {
      console.log('dataset.image :>> ', imgUrl);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

> Note: Few of you may feel that this seems like un-realistic situation
> that any developer can encounter. `cars` data that I have created
> above is just to demonstrate what I need but I actually needed this
> solution for much more complicated data and for a real project.